# LWUIT TextArea question

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

Is there any way to write in a `textArea` without going to a LCDUI window?
I want to edit my `textArea` in my LWUIT app but everytime I try to do this, the app send me to a LCDUI window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the LWUIT edit control trigger you can use the following code.

```
textArea.setNativeTextboxTrigger(false);
```

You need to implement the following code in the LWUIT TextArea source code

```
static final String CLIENT_PROPERTY_FIRE_ACTION_TIMES = "FIRE-ACTION-TIMES";
static final String CLIENT_PROPERTY_DEAFULT_TEXT = "DEFAULT-TEXT";  


public void setNativeTextboxTrigger(boolean enable) {
        registerNativeTextboxTriggerEvent = enable;

         static final String CLIENT_PROPERTY_FIRE_ACTION_TIMES = "FIRE-ACTION-TIMES";
            static final String CLIENT_PROPERTY_DEAFULT_TEXT = "DEFAULT-TEXT";          
        try {
            if( registerNativeTextboxTriggerEvent ) {
                String text = null != ( text = getText() ) ? text : "";  
                this.putClientProperty(CLIENT_PROPERTY_DEAFULT_TEXT, text);
                this.putClientProperty(CLIENT_PROPERTY_FIRE_ACTION_TIMES, String.valueOf(0));
                final UIManager m = UIManager.getInstance();
                setNativeCommandsText(m.localize("ok", "OK"), m.localize("cancel", "Cancel"));
                this.addActionListener(nativeTriggerListener = getNativeTriggerActionListener());
            } else {
                this.putClientProperty(CLIENT_PROPERTY_DEAFULT_TEXT, null);
                this.putClientProperty(CLIENT_PROPERTY_FIRE_ACTION_TIMES, null);
                setNativeCommandsText(null, null);
                if( null != nativeTriggerListener ) {
                    this.removeActionListener(nativeTriggerListener);
                    nativeTriggerListener = null;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




       ActionListener getNativeTriggerActionListener() {
        return new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if( evt.getSource() instanceof TextArea ) {
                    final TextArea tar = (TextArea)evt.getSource();
                    final String textEntered = tar.getText().trim();
                    final String defaultText = (String)tar.getClientProperty(CLIENT_PROPERTY_DEAFULT_TEXT);
                    int fireActionTimes = Integer.parseInt((String)tar.getClientProperty(CLIENT_PROPERTY_FIRE_ACTION_TIMES));
                    ++fireActionTimes;
                    int value = fireActionTimes % 2;

                    if( 0 == value ) {
                        fireActionTimes = 0;
                        if( textEntered.equals("") || textEntered.toUpperCase().equals(defaultText.toUpperCase())) {
                            tar.setText(defaultText);
                        }
                        triggeredNativeToLwuit(tar);
                    } else
                    //Switching to native edit screen
                    if( 0 < value ) {
                        if( textEntered.toUpperCase().equals(defaultText.toUpperCase()) ) {
                            tar.setText("");
                        }
                        triggeredLwuitToNative(tar);
                    }                   
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I don´t find the `textArea.setNativeTextboxTrigger();` in the LWUIT API

Comment: check now i have changed the answer