# pointing cursor over textarea in lwuit

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textarea, lwuit-textfield

How do we set the cursor in `TextArea`? Mainly the cursor should be visible to the user.
The cursor is visible in the `TextField` where as it is not visible in the `TextArea`.How to set the cursor when the `TextArea` has focus?.

Comment: What you want to do is edit the TextArea like a TextField? That is not possible in LWUIT for now. You should keep an eye on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384781/lwuit-textarea-question

Comment: Ask it like a question and i will answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

LWUIT 1.5 supports a multi-line text field which has a cursor element.