# Why is it impossible to write text within a TextArea?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textarea

There are a `TextField` , a `ListBox` and a `TextArea` inside my `Form`. The `TextArea` is the last item. When navigating the items through the navigational button keys of the phone then I cannot see the `cursor` `blinking` in the `TextArea` and I cannot write text ! Although I know that the `cursor` is within the `TextArea` because there is no `blinking` `focus` in the two previous items. Here is the code :

```
public class CompteRendu extends Form implements FocusListener, DataChangedListener {
    private Container x1 = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    private Container x2 = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    private Container x3 = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    private Container x4 = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    private Container x5 = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    private Container CntnrYforAll = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    private Label dateL, lieuL, dossier, client, resultat;
    private Label dateData, dossierData, clientData;
    private TextField lieu;
    private int nbVKBshow;
    private ListBox resultatList;
    private TextArea compteRendu;
    public CompteRendu(boolean general)
    {
        super();
        if (general)
            setTitle("Compte rendu général");
        dateL       = new FicheLibelle("Date");
        lieuL       = new FicheLibelle("Lieu");
        dossier     = new FicheLibelle("Dossier");
        client      = new FicheLibelle("Client");
        resultat    = new FicheLibelle("Résultat");
        dateL.setPreferredW(Comparator.max(new int[]{dateL.getPreferredW(),lieuL.getPreferredW(),dossier.getPreferredW(),client.getPreferredW(),resultat.getPreferredW()}));
        lieuL.setPreferredW(Comparator.max(new int[]{dateL.getPreferredW(),lieuL.getPreferredW(),dossier.getPreferredW(),client.getPreferredW(),resultat.getPreferredW()}));
        dossier.setPreferredW(Comparator.max(new int[]{dateL.getPreferredW(),lieuL.getPreferredW(),dossier.getPreferredW(),client.getPreferredW(),resultat.getPreferredW()}));
        client.setPreferredW(Comparator.max(new int[]{dateL.getPreferredW(),lieuL.getPreferredW(),dossier.getPreferredW(),client.getPreferredW(),resultat.getPreferredW()}));
        resultat.setPreferredW(Comparator.max(new int[]{dateL.getPreferredW(),lieuL.getPreferredW(),dossier.getPreferredW(),client.getPreferredW(),resultat.getPreferredW()}));
        dateData    = new Label(Formatage.dateToStringHH24(new Date()));
        dossierData = new Label();
        clientData  = new Label();
        lieu        = new ChpModif(100, this, this, null);
        resultatList = new ListBox(new String[]{"Oui","Non"},lieu.getPreferredH(),getPreferredW(),getPreferredH(),lieu.getSelectedStyle().getMargin(Component.TOP),lieu.getSelectedStyle().getMargin(Component.BOTTOM));
        compteRendu = new TextArea(5, 100);
        compteRendu.setGrowByContent(true);
        compteRendu.setFocusable(true);
        compteRendu.setEditable(true);
        x1.addComponent(dateL);
        x1.addComponent(dateData);
        x2.addComponent(lieuL);
        x2.addComponent(lieu);
        if (!general)
        {

        }
        x5.addComponent(resultat);
        x5.addComponent(resultatList);
        CntnrYforAll.addComponent(x1);
        CntnrYforAll.addComponent(x2);
        if (!general)
        {

        }
        CntnrYforAll.addComponent(x5);
        CntnrYforAll.addComponent(compteRendu);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER));
        addComponent(CntnrYforAll);
    }
```

So how to make cursor visible and permitting writing text when navigating into the TextArea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it. You have to use LWUIT TextField. Look at this:

[TextArea question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118510/pointing-cursor-over-textarea-in-lwuit)

[TextArea question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384781/lwuit-textarea-question)

Comment: Correct. Just to clarify, LWUIT has a multi-line text field starting with LWUIT 1.5